# XSSF (POI) - Changing the font on a pivot table

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table, xssf

I am using Apache POI 3.12:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
```

How do I change the font within a pivot table?
Examining the generated .xlsx after changing the font for one cell (I7) to size 8pt shows the following changes:

styles.xml, within the  tag as the 2nd entry:

```
<font>
    <sz val="8"/>
    <color indexed="8"/>
    <name val="Calibri"/>
    <family val="2"/>
    <scheme val="minor"/>
</font>

within the <cellXfs> tag as the 5th entry:
<xf numFmtId="0" fontId="1" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyNumberFormat="1" applyFont="1"/>

New tag: dxfs:
<dxfs count="1">
    <dxf>
        <font>
            <sz val="8"/>
        </font>
    </dxf>
</dxfs>
```

pivottable.xml

```
<formats count="1">
    <format dxfId="0">
        <pivotArea collapsedLevelsAreSubtotals="1" fieldPosition="0">
        <references count="2">
        <reference field="4294967294" count="1" selected="0">
        <x v="0"/>
        </reference>
        <reference field="0" count="1">
        <x v="0"/>
        </reference>
        </references>
        </pivotArea>
    </format>
</formats>
```

sheet1.xml

```
<c r="I7" s="4">
```

Note: I may close this as a self-answer as I am still trying to solve it myself.  However, I've been at this for almost a week.
[POI Pivot table sample](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/CreatePivotTable.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a full answer but is much more involved than the prior answer of using excel.

General Steps:

1. Create a spreadsheet with a pivot table in excel or use the [sample](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/CreatePivotTable.java) for poi.
2. Create a pivot cache definition.
3. Create a CTDxfs entry. This is "font" for tables.  (See other-answer)
4. Create a pivotArea definition with the CTDXfs id.  (See other-answer)

Step 2 looks so innocuous by itself but is the key to the whole process.  When Excel opens the .xlsx document, it re-verifies all of the pivotTable entries deleting any that no longer exist including the CTDXfs entry.  Then it generates the cache, then it applies any formatting.  However, all the formatting rules are deleted during the verification process if the cache doesn't exist yet!

Below is the code-block I used to generate the pivotCache.  This is far longer than a normal stackOverflow answer, but not sure if this is preferred or "general guidance" on how to do it.

If you need to maintain or extend this, rename the .xlsx to .zip, extract it, then look at xl\pivotTables\pivotTable1.xml, xl\pivotCache\pivotCacheDefinition1.xml before and after saving it in excel.  If this is working correctly, pivotCacheDefinition should be mostly unchanged after saving it in excel.

```
public class PivotUtilitiesExample {
    public static void updateCache(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable) {
        updateCache(pivotTable,STAxis.AXIS_ROW);
        updateCache(pivotTable,STAxis.AXIS_COL);
        updateCache(pivotTable,STAxis.AXIS_PAGE);
    }
    /**
     * Updates the pivotCacheDefinition.xml file.  This must be run before any formatting is done.
     * However, it must also be run *AFTER* the pivotTable's source data is created and all label definitions are defined.
     *   the labels are sorted by default.
     * @param pivotTable
     * @param rowLabel if true, updates rowLabels, if false, updates columnLabels.
     */
    private static void updateCache(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable,STAxis.Enum axisType) {
        XSSFSheet sheet=(XSSFSheet) pivotTable.getDataSheet();
        AreaReference pivotArea = new AreaReference(pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().
                getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheSource().getWorksheetSource().getRef());
        CellReference firstCell = pivotArea.getFirstCell();
        CellReference lastCell = pivotArea.getLastCell();
        List<Integer> labelColumns=getLabelColumns(pivotTable,axisType);

        for(int labelCtr=0;labelCtr<labelColumns.size();++labelCtr) {
            CTSharedItems sharedItems=getSharedItems(pivotTable,labelColumns.get(labelCtr));
            //The pivotField entry associated will be the nth axis="axisRow" entry where N is the row label #.
            CTPivotField pivotField=getPivotField(pivotTable,axisType,labelCtr);
            CTItems items=pivotField.getItems();

            ArrayList<String> toCache=new ArrayList<String>(lastCell.getRow()-firstCell.getRow());
            //To make this work, sharedItems and pivotFields must be properly populated.
            //sharedItems should look like:
            //<cacheField name="Names" numFmtId="0"> (Cell A1)
            //<sharedItems count="3">                (Count of unique rows)
            //<s v="Jane"/>                          (Cell B1)
            //<s v="Tarzan"/>                        (Cell C1)
            //<s v="Terk"/>                          (Cell D1)
            //</sharedItems>
            //pivotFields should have an entry like this:
            //<pivotField axis="axisRow" showAll="0">
            //<items count="4">
            //<item x="0"/>
            //<item x="1"/>
            //<item x="2"/>
            //<item t="default"/>
            //</items>
            //Initially, POI will populate with:
            //<pivotField axis="axisRow" showAll="0">
            //<items count="4">
            //<item t="default"/>
            //<item t="default"/>
            //<item t="default"/>
            //<item t="default"/>
            //</items>
            //Start with firstCell.getRow()+1 since the first row is the column name.
            for(int i=firstCell.getRow()+1;i<=lastCell.getRow();++i) {
                String s=sheet.getRow(i).getCell(firstCell.getCol()+labelColumns.get(labelCtr)).getStringCellValue();
                //Only add unique entries.
                if(!toCache.contains(s))
                    toCache.add(s);
            }
            //Blank entries cannot be sorted unless they are specially entered after an M tag.
            //  For most projects this'll be overkill.
            boolean containsBlank=false;
            if(toCache.contains("")) {
                toCache.remove("");
                containsBlank=true;
            }
            //Remove the old cache list.
            for(int i=items.sizeOfItemArray()-1;i>=0;--i)
                items.removeItem(i);
            for(int i=sharedItems.sizeOfBArray()-1;i>=0;--i)
                sharedItems.removeB(i);
            for(int i=sharedItems.sizeOfDArray()-1;i>=0;--i)
                sharedItems.removeD(i);
            for(int i=sharedItems.sizeOfEArray()-1;i>=0;--i)
                sharedItems.removeE(i);
            for(int i=sharedItems.sizeOfMArray()-1;i>=0;--i)
                sharedItems.removeM(i);
            for(int i=sharedItems.sizeOfNArray()-1;i>=0;--i)
                sharedItems.removeN(i);
            for(int i=sharedItems.sizeOfSArray()-1;i>=0;--i)
                sharedItems.removeS(i);
            sharedItems.setCount(sharedItems.getDomNode().getChildNodes().getLength());
            items.setCount(items.sizeOfItemArray());
            for(int i=0;i<toCache.size();++i) {
                CTString string;
                CTItem item;
                string=sharedItems.addNewS();
                sharedItems.setCount(sharedItems.getDomNode().getChildNodes().getLength());
                string.setV(toCache.get(i));

                item=items.addNewItem();
                items.setCount(items.sizeOfItemArray());
                item.setX(i);
            }
            //Create the special blank tag.
            if(containsBlank) {
                int mPosition;
                sharedItems.addNewM();
                mPosition=sharedItems.sizeOfSArray();
                CTString s=sharedItems.addNewS();
                s.setV("");
                s.setU(true);
                sharedItems.setCount(sharedItems.getDomNode().getChildNodes().getLength());
                sharedItems.setContainsBlank(true);
                CTItem item=items.addNewItem();
                item.setM(true);
                item.setX(sharedItems.sizeOfSArray());
                item=items.addNewItem();
                item.setX(mPosition);
                items.setCount(items.sizeOfItemArray());
            }
            //Add the t="default" entry, required for subtotals.
            if(!pivotField.isSetDefaultSubtotal() || pivotField.getDefaultSubtotal()==true) {
                CTItem item;
                item=items.addNewItem();
                items.setCount(items.sizeOfItemArray());
                item.setT(STItemType.DEFAULT);
            }
        }
    }
    //Returns the label columns for all AXIS.  Default POI only has a method for RowLabelColumns.
    private static List<Integer> getLabelColumns(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable,STAxis.Enum axisType) {
        List<Integer> labelColumns;
        if(axisType.equals(STAxis.AXIS_ROW))
            labelColumns=pivotTable.getRowLabelColumns();
        else if(axisType.equals(STAxis.AXIS_COL)) {
            List<CTField> fieldList = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields().getFieldList();
            labelColumns=new ArrayList(fieldList.size());
            for(CTField field:fieldList)
                labelColumns.add(field.getX());
        } else if(axisType.equals(STAxis.AXIS_PAGE)) {
            List<CTPageField> fieldList = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPageFields().getPageFieldList();
            labelColumns=new ArrayList(fieldList.size());
            for(CTPageField field:fieldList)
                labelColumns.add(field.getFld());
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Error, STAxis: "+axisType+" is not supported");
        }
        return labelColumns;
    }
    //Returns the sharedItems entry associated with a particular labelColumn.
    private static CTSharedItems getSharedItems(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable,int columnIndex) {
        XSSFSheet sheet=(XSSFSheet) pivotTable.getDataSheet();
        AreaReference pivotArea = new AreaReference(pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().
                getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheSource().getWorksheetSource().getRef());
        CellReference firstCell = pivotArea.getFirstCell();
        String labelName=sheet.getRow(firstCell.getRow()).getCell(firstCell.getCol()+columnIndex).getStringCellValue();
        List<CTCacheField> cacheFieldList = pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldList();
        CTSharedItems sharedItems=null;
        //The sharedItem entry associated will have name=labelColumn's name.
        for(int i=0;i<cacheFieldList.size();++i)
            if(labelName.equals(cacheFieldList.get(i).getName())) {
                sharedItems=cacheFieldList.get(i).getSharedItems();
                break;
            }
        //Should never be true.
        if(sharedItems==null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error, unable to find sharedItems entry in pivotCacheDefinition.xml");
        }
        return sharedItems;
    }
    //Return the nth pivotField entry from the pivotTable definition of a particular Axis.
    private static CTPivotField getPivotField(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable,STAxis.Enum axisType,int index) {
        CTPivotFields pivotFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields();
        CTPivotField pivotField=null;
        for(int i=0,axisRowNum=-1;i<pivotFields.getPivotFieldList().size();++i) {
            if(axisType.equals(pivotFields.getPivotFieldList().get(i).getAxis()))
                ++axisRowNum;
            if(axisRowNum==index) {
                pivotField=pivotFields.getPivotFieldList().get(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(pivotField==null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Error, unable to find pivotField entry in pivotTable.xml");
        return pivotField;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer since it requires using excel to setup rather than pure poi.

General steps:

1. Create a spreadsheet with a pivot table in excel or use the [sample](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/CreatePivotTable.java) for poi.
2. Open the spreadsheet in excel and **save**.
3. Open the spreadsheet in poi.
4. Create a CTDxfs entry.  This is "font" for tables.
5. Create a pivotArea definition with the CTDXfs id.

On to the code:

```
private static CTFormats getFormats(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable) {
    CTFormats formats = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getFormats();
    if(formats==null)
        formats=pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewFormats();
    return formats;
}
private static int createDXFs(XSSFWorkbook wb,int font) {
    CTDxfs dxfs=wb.getStylesSource().getCTStylesheet().getDxfs();
    if(dxfs==null)
        dxfs=wb.getStylesSource().getCTStylesheet().addNewDxfs();
    dxfs.setCount(dxfs.getCount()+1);
    CTDxf dxf=dxfs.addNewDxf();
    CTFontSize fontSize=dxf.addNewFont().addNewSz();
    fontSize.setVal(font);
    return (int) dxfs.getCount()-1;
}
public static void setAxisFont(CTFormats pivotTableFormats,int dxfId) {
    CTFormat format=pivotTableFormats.addNewFormat();
    format.setDxfId(dxfId);
    CTPivotArea pivotArea = format.addNewPivotArea();
    pivotArea.setDataOnly(false);
    pivotArea.setLabelOnly(true);
    pivotArea.setOutline(false);
    pivotArea.setFieldPosition(0L);
    pivotArea.setAxis(STAxis.AXIS_ROW);
    pivotArea.setType(STPivotAreaType.BUTTON);
}
public static void setColHeaderFont(CTFormats pivotTableFormats,int dxfId,int colInd) {
    CTFormat format=pivotTableFormats.addNewFormat();
    format.setDxfId(dxfId);
    CTPivotArea pivotArea = format.addNewPivotArea();
    pivotArea.setDataOnly(false);
    pivotArea.setLabelOnly(true);
    pivotArea.setOutline(false);
    CTPivotAreaReferences references = pivotArea.addNewReferences();
    CTPivotAreaReference reference = references.addNewReference();

    reference.setField(new Long(Integer.MAX_VALUE)*2);
    CTIndex x = reference.addNewX();
    x.setV(colInd); //Column
}
public static void setLabelFont(CTFormats pivotTableFormats,int dxfId, int rowInd) {
    CTFormat format=pivotTableFormats.addNewFormat();
    format.setDxfId(dxfId);
    CTPivotArea pivotArea = format.addNewPivotArea();
    pivotArea.setDataOnly(false);
    pivotArea.setLabelOnly(true);
    pivotArea.setFieldPosition(0L);
    CTPivotAreaReferences references = pivotArea.addNewReferences();
    CTPivotAreaReference reference = references.addNewReference();

    reference.setField(0L);
    CTIndex x = reference.addNewX();
    x.setV(rowInd); //Row
}
public static void setDataElementFont(CTFormats pivotTableFormats,int dxfId,int col,int row) {
    CTFormat format=pivotTableFormats.addNewFormat();
    format.setDxfId(dxfId);
    CTPivotArea pivotArea = format.addNewPivotArea();
    //Default values, don't need to explicitly define.
    //pivotArea.setDataOnly(true);
    //pivotArea.setLabelOnly(false);
    CTPivotAreaReferences references = pivotArea.addNewReferences();
    CTPivotAreaReference reference = references.addNewReference();

    reference.setField(new Long(Integer.MAX_VALUE)*2);
    CTIndex x = reference.addNewX();
    x.setV(col); //Column
    reference = references.addNewReference();
    reference.setField(0L);
    x = reference.addNewX();
    x.setV(row); //Row
}
```

Notes:

- **setOutline(false)** is required to access the column headers.
- **setDataOnly(false)** allows the change to affect the label as well as the data.
- **setLabelOnly(true)** restricts the change to the label value only.  If you want to change the whole column/row, set to false.
- Reference field value of unsigned int max value defines the reference as a column, the other valid value is 0 which defines the reference as a row.
- If the col/row reference is undefined such as in setColHeaderFont/setLabel font, it affects the whole column/row.  This may be desirable for formatting particular columns.

*Warning* The poi-ooxml-schemas used by maven for poi 3.12 does not include CTFormats.  This can be overriden by excluding it and including the 1.1 version:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```